# power of 2 with shr and shl - Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

How I can make a power of 2 with shl and shr in assembly *86 ?

I need to do 2^13.

I tried but without success :(

I'm using 8086 assembly with emu8086.

Here's my try:

```
org 100h

mov ax,1 ; ax = 1.
shl ax,13   

mov ah, 0
int 16h
ret
```

My problem is how to present that in 16 bits and not in 8 bits.

Comment: What is the problem you're experiencing?

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple math problem.  What you want is this:

```
mov ax,1
shl ax,13
```

That will give you 1*2^13 instead of 2*2^13 = 2^14 which is what your code does.

Comment: The answer comes to 128. How do I increase the amount of bits

Comment: ax is 16 bits, mov ax,1 | shl ax,13 should result in 8192. How are you debugging this? If this is 8086, it may not have a shl ax,13, which could cause unexpected results. In this case try mov ax,1 | mov cl,13 | shl ax,cl .